# Error handling in redshift stored procedures

Tags: amazon-redshift

When I tried to add exception handling in redshift stored procedure getting below error.

Please find the code below:

```
CREATE TABLE employee (firstname varchar, lastname varchar);
INSERT INTO employee VALUES ('Tomas','Smith');
CREATE TABLE employee_error_log (message varchar);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_employee_sp() AS
$$
BEGIN
    UPDATE employee SET firstname = 'Adam' WHERE lastname = 'Smith';
    EXECUTE 'select invalid';
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RAISE INFO 'An exception occurred.';
    INSERT INTO employee_error_log VALUES ('Error message: ' || SQLERRM);
END;
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Error: Amazon invalid operation: ROLLBACK cannot be invoked from a procedure that is executing in an atomic context.

Anyone please provide the solution here.

One more query in redshift is how we can log an error message and error code in table. For example how we can log a DML or DDL errors in some table  which occurs inside the stored procedure. Any system table available for getting error code and error message of DML errors like error_messages table in teradata.

Comment: Maybe, have a look at `STL_ERROR`

Answer (score 1):

Change the connection to `autocommit=true`. It will work.

Comment: This works perfectly. Just in case, if you are using psycopg in Python for the connection, then use conn.autocommit = True where conn is the reference to your connection.